# fork(): Can't access to child process

Tags: c, process, fork, fork-join

I'm trying to make a program that creates 10 child processes by using `fork()`.
By reading sem_overview I know that if `fork()`:

- returns 0 -> child process
- return -1 -> error
- return something > 0 -> the return value is the parent process pid

  ```
    pid_t pid[10];
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {

        pid[n] = fork();
        sleep(1);

        printf("pid: %d\n", pid[n]);

        if (pid[n] < 0) { /* error occurred */
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed: %s", errno);
            return 1;
        }
        else if (pid[n] == 0) { /* child process */
            printf("child process");
            sprintf(s, "%d", n);
            execlp("./child", "child", s, NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "Exec Failed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            //printf("Parent pid: %d\n", pid[n]);
        }
  }
  ```

But my code prints this:

```
pid: 147190
pid: 0
pid: 147192
pid: 0
pid: 147211
pid: 0
pid: 147245
pid: 0
pid: 147276
pid: 0
pid: 147285
pid: 0
pid: 147294
pid: 0
pid: 147303
pid: 0
pid: 147328
pid: 0
pid: 147360
...
```

and never goes to the child process, why?

Comment: Does it do the same if you put a `\n` in the `printf` for 'child process'? I'm wondering if the output gets stuck in the `stdio` buffer, which gets dropped on the `execlp`.

Comment: @abligh I tried and now it seems to print "child process", thank you!!

Comment: `> 0` is the child process PID, not the parent process PID.

Comment: `fork()` returns twice (when successful): the new `pid` to the parent (a positive integer) and a `0` to the child.  Your output indicates that your children are indeed executing (see the `pid: 0`s).

Comment: Several other suggestions: *i*, consider defaulting to use `snprintf`, `strncpy`, etc. in place of their unbounded counterparts; *ii*, consider using `\n` or `fflush` to trigger stream flushing; *iii*, whenever `fork`ing, consider immediately switching the return to help ensure context clarity (e.g., `if ( ( pid = fork() ) > 0 ) { /* parent */ } else if ( pid == 0 ) { /* child */ } else { /* error */ }`); and, *iv*, be careful with `fork`-loop `return`s, `exit`s, etc., as they'll only affect the process from which they're called (e.g., children may keep running).